# How can I tie a stripe webhook to the flask session information of the customer who purchased the product?

Tags: flask, stripe-payments

I'm creating an online quiz for which the user can pay $5 to get the results. At the end of the assessment, if the user clicks the purchase button, it takes them to a stripe hosted checkout page, and then to a thank you page. The webhook is successfully set up. The problem is that when I try to access information from session (I'm using flask for the backend; session is essentially a cookie) it's a different instance of session than the user's instance. Since the user's answers are stored in the session, I need the webhook to tell the backend to analyze the answers of that specific session. Is that possible?

If anyone has a different solution I'd also love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Stripe Checkout session you can add a value to `client_reference_id`. This can be used to identify the customer or their quiz, etc.

See the Stripe documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id

This value forms part of the Stripe, Create a Session object.

When you get the Webhook payload back it'll tell you what the client_reference_id the webhook relates to so you can query your internal system

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is it possible to get a person's name from checkout.session.completed? Looking at the event I only see the email and client_reference_id, not the name.